# CameraX and MediaRecorder for recording video

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-camerax

I tried to use CameraX PreviewView here

```
            <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                android:id="@+id/camPreviewView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I'm able to use MediaProjection for recording video for whole screen.

But now, I need to record only the camera view.
I tried to use setPreviewDisplay from MediaRecorder, but since I'm using PreviewView I had no idea how to get the surface.

I also tried to used the setCamera from MediaRecorder, but it is deprecated. It suggest to use getSurface instead.

Is there any example to use MediaRecorder with CameraX PreviewView out there ?

There is VideoCapture for CameraX but for some reason, I can't use it.
I need to use MediaRecorder and CameraX PreviewView for recording file.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi @Lyn, did you resolve this? I also encounter the same problem with you.

Comment: @BG_TeMe Unfortunately, nope.... My final solution is providing options for user to use Media Recorder or CameraX with VideoCapture which is not ideal. Ideally I want to use MediaRecorder + CameraX, but we are run out of time and cannot find the solution so we just use what we have. It is really unfortunate though...